# Why is my 2005 Hyundai Sonata GLS hard to start only after putting gas in

Tags: starting

Why is my 2005 Hyundai Sonata 2.7 V6 hard to start only after putting gas in ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) Which engine do you have? Do you have any fault codes or anything? Does this happen all the time or just a one off? It could be bad fuel

Comment: I have the 2.7 liter 6 cylinder. It has done it a couple of times and now it wont start at all

Comment: No fault codes are present

Answer (score 1):

One of the few things affected at fuel fill is tank pressure and the vapor recovery system.

My guess is you are adversely affecting the carbon cannister vapor recovery system during fuel fill.

First i want to verify you are NOT doing a fuel fill to the tippy top. This is really a BAD thing to do. When you are filling up the tank and the pump clicks off STOP right there. If you are doing multiple fills / click off cycle you are flooding the vapor recovery system with liquid gasoline.

If not an overfull issue, It’s possible that something else is awry with the carbon cannister recovery system or gas cap. Check that gas cap seals correctly. Check the air inlet to the carbon breather. They often get clogged (Spiders are attracted to the gasoline smell and spider webs clog stuff up. )